# how can I discover what keys are being sent when I press a mouse button?

Tags: mouse, visual-studio-2008

I'd like to map my Logitech MX Revolution keys in Visual Studio. More importantly, I'd like to do it *without* installing any software.

Is this possible? I specifically want to map the two side buttons to View.NavigateBackward and View.NavigateForward. But I'm not sure what those keys are mapped to right now. I thought they were mapped to Ctrl-Tab and Shift-Ctrl-Tab, since they seem to behave that way in Notepad++, but that isn't working in VS.

I'm on the work computer, which means 2 problems: I'm in Windows XP and installing software is frowned upon/monitored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AutoHotKey, then compile the script into a standalone executable.

```
#IfWinActive, [Part of the titlebar for VS08 (I don't use that IDE, personally, so I don't know what the window title is)
XButton1::[whatever the key combo is for backward]
XButton2::[whatever the key combo is for forward]
#IfWinActive
```

in a .ahk file, then right click and hit "Compile". Not quite perfect, but the

Comment: 'the...' Don't leave us hanging! :)

Comment: Oh dear, I've forgotten what I was going to write! It shall have to be like one of those books where you write the ending yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: 3 years later, ran into same problem again and found this question that I asked. Unfortunately, this answer was not helpful. I think a key logger _might_ do it but installing that well... seems like a bad idea.